# Image rotation Android

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

I am working on android. I want to create a rotating image and  select parts on it. For example if the image is a human head then while its rotating, the ears can be selected. Now I did the image part selection, but I don't know how to rotate it? Can somebody show me an easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways to rotate a image, i put the simple with xml.

First inside directory `res` create a directory with the name `anim`

inside the directory `anim` create a file xml with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1000"
    >    
</rotate>
```

this code is the instruction to make a image rotate.

finally your main activity must look like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    ImageView imagen; //declare the image will use
    Button boton; // this button will activie de rotation
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
        boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);

        boton.setOnClickListener(this); 

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bt:
            Animation rotacion; // declare an animation
            rotacion  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotar);

            rotacion.reset();
            imagen.startAnimation(rotacion);

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) what if I want to change the image while rotating. I mean while its rotating from left to right the other side of the brain comes. @josedlujan

Answer (score 0):

You should use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html class to make animation and animate your view